# Twitter Bootstrap - Same heights on fluid columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to get two fluid column wells with uneven column data length to be the same height?

Comment: sorry! the search came up right after i posted

Comment: Actually, the other post is a fixed layout and the solution does not seem to work for fluid columns

Answer (score 26):

Here's a responsive CSS solution, based on adding a large padding and an equally large negative margin to each column, then wrapping the entire row in in a class with overflow hidden.

```
.col{
margin-bottom: -99999px;
padding-bottom: 99999px;
background-color:#ffc;
}

.col-wrap{  
overflow: hidden;   
}
```

You can see it working at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/teFYS/)

EDIT

A variation if you want equal height wells or columns with rounded corners:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/4Pyhj/

EDIT

Another variation with equal height wells or columns with rounded corners, this time for Bootstrap 3
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/D4xdE/

It's more or less the same as with Bootstap 2, but with some refinements to accomodate a change in how BS spaces the column grids now.

Comment: Because this just makes the columns really large and hides the "really large" bit it doesn't work when columns have rounded borders, as the bottom of each column is hidden.

Comment: How about the same effect with Bootstrap 3?