# How to match all col height to row height in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this case, the height:100% in col is not works, because .row is no height

```
div[class*='col']
{
    border:solid 1px #000;
    height:100%;
}
.row
{
    border:solid 1px #000;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I set a height for row, all cols can match row height. But I don't want to set the height for row, because I want the row height can match to the biggest col height. How to use css to make all cols height 100%?

```
div[class*='col']
{
    border:solid 1px #000;
    height:100%;
}
.row
{
    border:solid 1px #000;
    height:500px;
}


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819816/bootstrap-3-trying-to-create-columns-with-equal-heights helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `display: table-cell;`.

Here is the updated [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oiBsI)

```
 div[class*='col']
        {
            border:solid 1px #000;
            height:100%;
          display: table-cell;
          float: none
        }
        .row
        {
            border:solid 1px #000;
            /* height:500px; */
          display: table;
          width: 100%

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you are asking is not possible without some fixed reference height.

There are two alternatives that you can apply here:

1. Create .col divs with fixed height and put overflow property auto so if content goes beyond your fixed height scrollbar will be visible here is `jfiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/9FFgN/1/
2. Use jquery to solve this problem